# How do I verify method is invoked in the correct order among mock objects in Spock?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking, spock

In my unit tests, I have 2 Mock objects, let's call them `Book book` and `Shelf shelf`. I want to ensure that the `repair()` method if the `book` is called first by the piece of code I'm testing before it is put back to the `shelf` via `putBack(Book)` method of `Shelf` class.

Here's a quick illustration:

```
def "Organize damaged books"() {

    given:
    Book book = Mock(Book)
    Shelf shelf = Mock(Shelf)

    when:
    library.returnDamaged(book)

    then:
    1 * book.repair()
    1 * shelf.putBack(book)

}
```

The test above will pass even if in the `returnDamaged` method, I call `shelf.putBack()` first before `book.repair()`. I tried doing:

```
1 * shelf.putBack(book) >> {
    1 * book.repair()
}
```

But the test still passes regardless of which comes first.

Comment: Are you certain that `shelf.putBack()` is throwing an exception when the book has not been repaired?

Comment: There's no need for shelves to do that.

Answer (score 4):

From Spock's documentation on [Interaction Based Testing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_invocation_order):

> To avoid over-specification, Spock defaults to allowing any invocation order, provided that the specified interactions are eventually satisfied…in those cases where invocation order matters, you can impose an order by splitting up interactions into multiple `then:` blocks.

So if you want to enforce invocation order, all you need to do is split the assertion into multiple `then` blocks:

```
then:
1 * book.repair()

then:
1 * shelf.putBack(book)
```